# Remove eval from method using dynamic variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eval, rubocop

The following method is passed a `:symbol` which correlates to both a method name and an instance variable set via `attr_accessor :symbol`. The only way I have been able to make this work is via eval.  Is there a way around this?

```
def collection_exists?(event_list)
  return unless self.class.method_defined?(event_list)
  eval("self.#{event_list.to_s}").any?
end
```

Comment: Your question is unclear: you say that there is a symbol which "correlates to both a method name and an instance variable", but *how* does it "correlate to them"? Also, in what way is this question related to [tag:ruby-on-rails] and [tag:rubocop]?

Comment: You've seen @Jörg's question. Why haven't you answered?

Comment: Please read the threads below, we have addressed this question.  Rubocop flags eval, and this is inside a rails application.

Comment: When valid questions are not answered it does not go unnoticed. Among other things, answering questions is just common courtesy. Don't forget that for Ruby to notify a member that a comment has been left for them the comment must include the member's user name (or an abbreviated form of it) preceded by an ampersand (e.g., @JörgWMittag).

Comment: I understand @CarySwoveland and let's be clear there were 3 of us collaborating below if you check out the threads.  It is easy to make this assumption, but in reality it is easy to see something like this fall through the cracks.  I was working to address the answers first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [**`public_send`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send)

```
  def collection_exists?(event_list)
    send(event_list).any?
  end
```

Comment: Please never use `send` to call public methods. Use `public_send` instead.

Comment: it is not a public method though, it is an instance variable? your original post worked as send(event_list).any?

Comment: @mudasobwa it is BOTH a method name and an instance variable name. thoughts?

Comment: @DeepakMahakale also, as a thought here, the self is redundant before the send and is flagged via rubocop...

Comment: @chrishough FYI: the same name cannot be shared between method name and instance variable name due to ruby restrictions on names.

Comment: Yes that would create problem, lets say you are expecting the value of variable, but you will get result of method

Comment: And yes you can omit the `self`

Comment: oh, I see now, I mis-spoke, it is only an instance variable, not a method.  so the symbol would be :shipment_event_list and self.shipment_event_list

Comment: In that case you don't need `self`

Comment: thank you, since you posted first I tossed you credit

Answer (score 1):

You might use one of the following options:

1. [Object#`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-method):

   ```
   method(event_list.to_sym).call.any?
   ```
2. [Object#`public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send)

   ```
   public_send(event_list.to_sym).any?
   ```

Please note, that using `public_send` is safer, than [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-send), because latter does not care about the method's visibility and would work with `protected` and `private` methods smoothly, whereas `public_send` (as you'd guess from it's name) would raise if you try to call non-`public` method with it.

Also note, that you do not need `self` for reading values, it is implicit.

Comment: It is used for both a method name and an instance variable name as mentioned below. Thoughts?

Comment: @chrishough the only thought is that there is no such thing as "both a method name and an instance variable"

Comment: @chrishough no probs. Make sure to go through the docs I linked ;)

Comment: I mis-spoke, it is only an instance variable, not a method. so the symbol would be :shipment_event_list and self.shipment_event_list, my mistake, thoughts?

Comment: @chrishough I see you accepted the answer. And you edited it. And your edit to it means you have not read a word from neither accepted one nor from mine. Meeh... :\

Comment: actually I was reading both, but his was posted first and addressed the issue.  it was not related to the method, it was an instance variable.

Comment: @chrishough I meant usage of `send`, which was said few times in this thread to be dangerous and not needed for your case.

Comment: how would you recommend adjusting it then? it is calling a dynamic instance variable name?

Comment: @chrishough `public_send` is a way to go here, because a reading a value of instance variable is as well *calling a method* :)

Comment: that throws the error "protected method" as it is a private instance variable, thoughts?

Comment: @chrishough instance variable are always private unless you have a method to access them. Well, nevermind. If `public_send` does not work, then use `send`, but later you will realize that such design is fragile and you should rely only on public interface.

Comment: ok, I am not saying I do not want to use it, I am saying it DOES not work.  What I mentioned was the instance variable falls under protected, not public.

protected
attr_accessor :symbol

Comment: I am down to switch credit, but do you see what I am referencing now?

Comment: @chrishough I never tried to convince you in changing the accepted answer, so please leave it as is :) I truly to say do not see the whole picture and pretty sure you're mixing up terminology, that is why I am afraid I can't conclude anything. As to `protected attr_accessor :symbol` - `attr_accessor` is a class instance method, so having it preceded with `protected` is somewhat senseless and I do not understand why would you do that. Moreover, `protected attr_accessor :symbol` ***would raise an exception***.

Comment: oh no worries, I am just trying to be thorough and learn from this thread.  in this case the instance variables are protected b/c classes that inherit from this class need to access them.  they are not methods.  my understanding is that public_send only works with public instance variables or methods?